# How do i correct a files extension?

Tags: python, file, mime-types, rename

I started programming in Python a couple of days ago and I have a problem I couldn't solve yet.
I want to correct a files file extension by guessing its mimetype.
I tried this:

```
new_file_name = mimetypes.guess_extension(mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)))
os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)
```

Why doesnt it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mimetypes` uses the existing extension to guess the file type. Use [`magic`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/) instead to examine the contents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i dont really want my program to have more dependencies? Isn't there another way?

Comment: Other than picking a random extension and hoping it's the right one? No.